# Compare two dates in python and ignoring microseconds

Tags: python

I am inserting a date_added date time value into mysql 5.5 which does not support datetime(6) and this is causing an AssertionError when running the following unit test

```
foo.date_added = timezone.now()

self.assertEquals(only_foo_in_database.date_added, foo.date_added)
```

which leads to

```
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 2, 6, 48, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 2, 6, 48, 56, 677255, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

How can I compare the two datetime values ignoring the microseconds?

Comment: IMO this question is improved if you remove the mysql component: removing tag mysql and write it has if mysql was not part of the problem, like the title suggests.

Comment: feel free to edit J.C.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set microsecond as `0` using [`datetime.datetime.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 2, 16, 25, 59, 444433)
>>> d.replace(microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 2, 16, 25, 59)
```

---

```
self.assertEquals(only_foo_in_database.date_added.replace(microsecond=0),
                  foo.date_added.replace(microsecond=0))
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

Using [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
d1 = datetime.datetime(2013,9,2,6,48,56)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2013,9,2,6,48,56,677255)
self.assertTrue(abs(d1 - d2) < datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
```

Comment: @NicholasMurray, Estimate the time without `self.assert*` statement. It should not take much time.

Comment: `d1 == d2 - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=d2.microsecond)`  Not as good as your two answers.

Answer (score 23):

You can use assertAlmostEqual in unittest

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz
self.assertAlmostEqual(
    only_foo_in_database.date_added, foo.date_added,
    delta=tz.timedelta(seconds=1))
```

Comment: `assertAlmostEqual(t1, t2, delta=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))` is a good trick. There's no reason to use django utils at all, though.